# How to reduce the render of tikzpicture

Tags: tikz-pgf

How to reduce the size of the brace and to customize its color to red ? I'm just trying to reduce the render of the tikzpicture.

```
\documentclass[]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit,calc,positioning,decorations.pathreplacing,matrix}

\begin{document}   

\begin{tikzpicture}[decoration={brace},scale=2] 
\node [rotate=90] (A) {A}; 
\node [fit=(A)] (fit) {};              
\draw [decorate,line width=1pt] 
  ([yshift=-5pt]fit.south west) -- ([yshift=5pt]fit.north west);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this?

```
\documentclass[]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit,calc,positioning,decorations.pathreplacing,matrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [rotate=90,inner sep=0pt,text=red] (A) {A};
\draw [red,line cap=round,decoration={brace,amplitude=0.25ex},decorate,line width=1pt]
  (A.north west) -- (A.north east);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I have reduced the `inner sep` to 0pt, removed the `fit` and added the `scale` option directly to the node as it seems appropriate. I have also set the `line cap=round` (thanks to Heiko for noting) as it looks better.

Comment: Thanks, I've updated my post about the color choosen. How to make it red? (color of all of the render)

Comment: `line cap=round`?

Comment: But that way the font is very big. I'm just trying to reduce all of the render.

Comment: And to set the color of all of the render to red.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek Yes and thank you. It looks better with that option.